# Strange version problems with npm and karma

Tags: node.js, npm, karma-runner

## package.json

I have the following `package.json`

```
...
"devDependencies": {
    "karma-coverage": "~0.1.3",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~0.1.1",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "~0.1.2",
    "karma-html-reporter": "~0.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~0.1.3",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.1.1",
    "karma-safari-launcher": "~0.1.1",
    "karma-script-launcher": "~0.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.1.1",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.1.2",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.1.1",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.3",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-karma": "~0.6.2",
    "grunt-concurrent": "~0.4.2",
    "time-grunt": "~0.1.1",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "~0.2.0",
    "jshint-stylish": "~0.1.3"
},
"peerDependencies": {
    "karma": ">=0.10",
    "grunt": ">=0.4"
},
...
```

## > karma --version

When I call `karma --version` on the console, I get the following output:

```
> karma --version
Karma version: 0.12.16
```

## > npm install

When I afterwards call `npm install` I get the following error:

```
> npm install
npm WARN package.json jsdom@0.1.0 No README data
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jquery
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jquery
npm ERR! peerinvalid The package karma does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-coverage@0.1.5 wants karma@>=0.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-chrome-launcher@0.1.3 wants karma@>=0.9.3
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-firefox-launcher@0.1.3 wants karma@>=0.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-html-reporter@0.1.3 wants karma@>=0.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-jasmine@0.1.5 wants karma@>=0.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-phantomjs-launcher@0.1.4 wants karma@>=0.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-safari-launcher@0.1.1 wants karma@>=0.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-script-launcher@0.1.0 wants karma@>=0.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-karma@0.6.2 wants karma@~0.10.0

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.1.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /Projects/jsdom
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.10
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, open 'npm-debug.log'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, open 'npm-debug.log'] errno: 3, code: 'EACCES', path: 'npm-debug.log' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.1.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /Projects/jsdom
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.10
npm ERR! path npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, open 'npm-debug.log'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Projects/jsdom/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

## The problem

Why `npm` doesn't like my `karma`? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your peerDependancies appears to be wrong, you should be specifying the name of the package, and then the versionied packages it needs,

```
"name": "karma-coverage",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "karma": "0.9"
  }
}
```

[See the Documentation from npm](http://blog.nodejs.org/2013/02/07/peer-dependencies/)

although it looks like none of your packages need a particular version of karma, so you could just try adding "karma": "10.0" at the start of your dev dependancies

Comment: I'm unable to check your solution because my project template has gone from the time I've posted my question, but I'll mark your answer as the answer to my question therefore hoping that it might help someone else who has got into same problem